# my first app on phone gap created with errors

Tags: cordova

i have installed the environment in my system.I have created a phonegap project to android from the comment line , when i open the project in eclipse it shows error and wont run this is the errors file
`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type sopickapp must override or implement a supertype method soapp.java  ‪/soapp/src/com/soapp   line 28 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   soapp.java  ‪/soapp/src/com/soapp‬  line 30 Java Problem
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved    soapp.java  ‪/soapp/src/com/soapp‬  line 23 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   soapp.java  ‪/soapp/src/com/soapp   line 25 Java Problem
Config cannot be resolved   soapp.java  ‪/soappp/src/com/ssoapp‬    line 32 Java Problem`

```
    package com.soappsopickapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class sopickapp extends DroidGap
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
            super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
            //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
        }
    }
```

Comment: just added the errors